# books v. reference-request

Tags: discussion

Why don't we make https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books and https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request mutually exclusive? So that "reference" in [reference-request] excludes books? Redundant to have both tags in same question.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me there is no such feature as a mutually exclusive tag list, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153379/create-a-list-of-mutually-exclusive-tags).